# jquery to get xml, file urls ending with x_.000 instead of file name

Tags: 2010, jquery, xml

I'm trying to return the URL of some attachments for a topic. I try to do the following to receive the url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    GetFiles();

});

    function GetFiles() {
        var method = "GetListItems";
        var list = "Session Schedule";
        var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>" +
            '<FieldRef Name="ID"/>'+
            '<FieldRef Name="Title"/>'+
            '<FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu"/>'+
            '<FieldRef Name="Created"/>'+
            '<FieldRef Name="EncodedAbsUrl"/>'+
 "<FieldRef Name='Date_x0020_and_x0020_Time' />" + 
 "<FieldRef Name='Attachments'/>" + "</ViewFields>";
        var query = "<Query>" + "<Where>" + "<Or>" + //"<Or>" +
         "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Status\" /><Value Type='Text'>Confirmed</Value></Eq>" + 
         "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Status\" /><Value Type='Text'>Ready</Value></Eq>" + 
         //"</Or>" + "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Status\" /><Value Type='Text'>Completed</Value></Eq>" + 
         "</Or>" + "</Where>" + "<OrderBy>" + "<FieldRef Name=\"Date_x0020_and_x0020_Time\"/>" + 
         "</OrderBy>" + "</Query>";



        $().SPServices({
            operation: method,
            async: false,
            listName: list,
            CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
            CAMLLimit: 1,
            CAMLQuery: query,
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            console.log("xData", xData);
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                 var url = $(this).attr("ows_EncodedAbsUrl")
                 console.log(url);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is the URL I receive is correct up until the file name, where I get 1_.000, 2_.000 and so on instead of the name of the actual file. The url thus doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? is it because the attachment is a ppt or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should be using GetAttachmentCollection not GetListItems

Can use GetListItems to get the ID from each list item. But to then get their attachments need to use this instead:

http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetAttachmentCollection

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `EncodedAbsUrl` returns an *absolute Url of a File*, in case of List Item it has the following format:

```
http(s)://[site]/[web]/[list]/[item id]_.000
```

In order to return attachments using `SPServices` `GetListItems` operation, the following query option have to be included:

```
CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><IncludeAttachmentUrls>True</IncludeAttachmentUrls></QueryOptions>"
```

### How to retrieve list items with attachments using SPServices

```
function getListItems(listName,query,viewFields,rowLimit,complete) 
{
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        listName: listName,
        CAMLViewFields: viewFields,
        CAMLLimit: rowLimit,
        CAMLQuery: query,
        CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><IncludeAttachmentUrls>True</IncludeAttachmentUrls></QueryOptions>",
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            var items = [];    
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
               items.push($(this).get(0));
            });
            complete(items);
        }
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
getListItems('Requests','<Query/>','<ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Attachments"/></ViewFields>',1,printItemAttachments);

function printItemAttachments(items)
{
    for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++){
        var attachmentsValue = $(items[i]).attr("ows_Attachments");
        if(attachmentsValue == "0") {
           console.log('No attachments'); 
        }
        else {
           var attachmentUrls = attachmentsValue.substr(2,attachmentsValue.length-4).split(';#');    
           console.log(attachmentUrls);   
        }     
    };    
}
```